# Access Denied on private image styles but not on public

Tags: 7, media, files

I am allowing a user to upload images via FTP into my `private://` location as configured under File system. This location is owned by ftpuser:apache and has write permissions for both user and group.

Then my Content Type has a field called "picture file" which is the base filename of the image, e.g. IMG_9001.jpg

Note: I am using FTP instead of an Image/Media upload because the user will be uploading hundreds of images.

In my template, I do this:

```
$picture_file = $node->field_picture_file['und'][0]['value'];
$picture_file = 'private://' . $picture_file;
$picture_url = image_style_url('large', $picture_file);
```

This returns a correct URL with the itok parameter appended:

```
http://example.com/system/files/styles/large/private/IMG_9001.jpg?itok=xxxxxxxx
```

However, the image does not display. Going to the URL in another window gives an Access denied error. Even with

```
$conf['image_allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;
```

in my settings file, it still gives Access denied!

If I copy the file to the public:// location and changing the path it works. It's only the private:// location that doesn't work. Why wouldn't it work even chmodded to 777?

Comment: Do you have any other modules influencing file access, e.g a hook_file_download implementation?

Comment: @DavidThomas nothing custom. I looked through the list of contributed modules and nothing stuck out. Disabled `Media` and `File Entity` just in case but still Access denied

Comment: Anything unusual in .htaccess, and you're using clean urls?

Comment: @DavidThomas yes I am using clean URLs, and no htaccess has not been modified

Comment: @DavidThomas I gave up and am using timthumb to resize the images. Thanks for the help

Comment: core issue https://www.drupal.org/node/1440312 and https://www.drupal.org/node/1438940